# VB.Net Data Repeater Winforms - Filter data set using parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm currently building a windows forms application using VB.Net and am using a data repeater to display data from a view in a SQL database.

I'd like to filter the incoming data based on a variable set within the application. This could be a text box, dropdown control etc but currently it is just a VB variable (strSessionID as integer)

As I've created the Dataset, Databinding source, Table adaptor, TableAdaptorManger and Binding Navigator by dragging the datasource into the data repeater control there doesn't seem to be any VB code that I can update to parameterise the SQL query.

This may be really simple, but I'm used to being able to do this in webforms using the query builder which lets you select a parameter value from URL, Cookie etc. Winforms doesn't seem to have the same ability though.

It may be possible to filter the dataset post fill and remove the entries I don't want using VB, but I was hoping to be able to amend the query so that it just doesn't bring back the data it doesn't need in the first place.

Can anyone advise how I'm best to do this please?

Regards

PS I'm Using VS 2012 if that makes a difference.

Current VB associated with the form:

```
Public Class Process_Selection

Private Sub LB_INTRO_TEXT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LB_INTRO_TEXT.Click

End Sub


Private Sub Process_Selection_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Process_Config_DataSet.VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIG' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIGTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Process_Config_DataSet.VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIG)

End Sub


Private Sub Process_Selection_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    LB_PROCESS_ID.Text = DataRepeater1.CurrentItem.Controls(4).Text
End Sub

Private Sub DataRepeater1_CurrentItemIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataRepeater1.CurrentItemIndexChanged
    Try
        LB_PROCESS_ID.Text = DataRepeater1.CurrentItem.Controls(4).Text
    Catch
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub BTN_TOGGLE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_TOGGLE.Click
    Call Execute_SQL_Toggle_Inclusion(LB_PROCESS_ID.Text, DataRepeater1.CurrentItem.Controls(0).Text, "PROCESS")
    'Rebind data repeater
    Process_Config_DataSet.Clear()
    VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIGTableAdapter.Adapter.Fill(Me.Process_Config_DataSet)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: can you show us the code you are using now

Comment: @GuidoG I've edited the Question to show the VB on the form currently. Regards

Comment: Some reading for you: [How to: Open a Dataset in the Dataset Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7973zb70.aspx) then [Create parameterized TableAdapter queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TnTinMn - thank you for your references.

I resolved this issue in the end by: 
1.) Right clicking on the table adaptor created by the GUI when I added the data repeater and clicking "Edit queries in data designer"
2.) Right clicked on the table adaptor in the designer view and clicked configure.
3.) Amended the SQL so that is included a WHERE clause that looked like: 
    WHERE SESSIONID = @SESSION
4.) Saved the changes then updated the vb code behind my form, changing the delivered string to fill the table adaptor:

Me.VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIGTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Process_Config_DataSet.VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIG)

To:

Me.VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIGTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Process_Config_DataSet.VW_PROCESS_SESSION_OUTPUT_CONFIG, Module3.intSessionID)

Note that the parameter being passed to the query is Module3.intSessionID